# Issue installing pdftotext in Python 3.6 on CentOS due to poppler

Tags: linux, python-3.x, centos, pdftotext, poppler

I'm having some issues getting installing `pdftotext` in Python 3.6 (Anaconda 5.1.0) on CentOS.

Some quick notes first:

- I'm using CentOS 6.7 on VirtualBox
- I know it *can* work because my IT group has it installed on our server. **NOTE:** I found that our server *did* have the C++ wrapper installed and I'm trying to figure out how the got it.
- I'm trying to get an existing application to work, so I'm not looking for an alternative to `pdftotext` the library at this time.

I followed the instructions from the github repo and already tried this step:

Fedora, Red Hat, and friends:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++ pkgconfig poppler-cpp-devel python-devel redhat-rpm-config
```

But the problem seems to be around poppler-cpp-devel. I don't see that package within `yum search poppler`:

```
============================= N/S Matched: poppler =============================
poppler-devel.i686 : Libraries and headers for poppler
poppler-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and headers for poppler
poppler-glib.i686 : Glib wrapper for poppler
poppler-glib.x86_64 : Glib wrapper for poppler
poppler-qt.i686 : Qt3 wrapper for poppler
poppler-qt.x86_64 : Qt3 wrapper for poppler
poppler-qt4.i686 : Qt4 wrapper for poppler
poppler-qt4.x86_64 : Qt4 wrapper for poppler
poppler.i686 : PDF rendering library
poppler.x86_64 : PDF rendering library
poppler-data.noarch : Encoding files
poppler-glib-devel.i686 : Development files for glib wrapper
poppler-glib-devel.x86_64 : Development files for glib wrapper
poppler-qt-devel.i686 : Development files for Qt3 wrapper
poppler-qt-devel.x86_64 : Development files for Qt3 wrapper
poppler-qt4-devel.i686 : Development files for Qt4 wrapper
poppler-qt4-devel.x86_64 : Development files for Qt4 wrapper
poppler-utils.x86_64 : Command line utilities for converting PDF files
```

My IT group gave me the instructions of what they had attempted and I tried installing `poppler-devel` and `poppler-glib`. But every time I try `pip install pdftotext` I'm getting the following output:

```
[root@localhost stack]# pip install pdftotext
Collecting pdftotext
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/35/60094dbadd9de2035873390b1cac25e01da605844eba6a07a53a82fa4adc/pdftotext-2.1.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pdftotext
  Building wheel for pdftotext (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-1mu2f1n2/pdftotext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-khm9zova --python-tag cp36:
  /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pdftotext' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  gcc -pthread -B /root/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=0 -I/root/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c pdftotext.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pdftotext.o -Wall
  cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
  pdftotext.cpp:3:42: error: poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h: No such file or directory
  pdftotext.cpp:4:40: error: poppler/cpp/poppler-global.h: No such file or directory
  pdftotext.cpp:5:38: error: poppler/cpp/poppler-page.h: No such file or directory
  pdftotext.cpp:20: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘document’ with no type
  pdftotext.cpp:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
  pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘void PDF_clear(PDF*)’:
  pdftotext.cpp:26: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp:27: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘int PDF_create_doc(PDF*)’:
  pdftotext.cpp:66: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp:66: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:67: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘int PDF_unlock(PDF*, char*)’:
  pdftotext.cpp:75: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘int PDF_init(PDF*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
  pdftotext.cpp:105: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PDF_read_page(PDF*, int)’:
  pdftotext.cpp:119: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:119: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
  pdftotext.cpp:120: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:120: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘layout_mode’
  pdftotext.cpp:123: error: ‘page’ was not declared in this scope
  pdftotext.cpp:123: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
  pdftotext.cpp:129: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:129: error: expected initializer before ‘rect’
  pdftotext.cpp:130: error: ‘rect’ was not declared in this scope
  pdftotext.cpp:133: error: ‘layout_mode’ was not declared in this scope
  pdftotext.cpp:133: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:135: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:137: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
  pdftotext.cpp:138: error: type ‘<type error>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pdftotext
  Running setup.py clean for pdftotext
Failed to build pdftotext
Installing collected packages: pdftotext
  Running setup.py install for pdftotext ... error
    Complete output from command /root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-1mu2f1n2/pdftotext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ghuhvuhl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pdftotext' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -B /root/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=0 -I/root/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c pdftotext.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pdftotext.o -Wall
    cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
    pdftotext.cpp:3:42: error: poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h: No such file or directory
    pdftotext.cpp:4:40: error: poppler/cpp/poppler-global.h: No such file or directory
    pdftotext.cpp:5:38: error: poppler/cpp/poppler-page.h: No such file or directory
    pdftotext.cpp:20: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘document’ with no type
    pdftotext.cpp:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
    pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘void PDF_clear(PDF*)’:
    pdftotext.cpp:26: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp:27: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘int PDF_create_doc(PDF*)’:
    pdftotext.cpp:66: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp:66: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:67: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘int PDF_unlock(PDF*, char*)’:
    pdftotext.cpp:75: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘int PDF_init(PDF*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
    pdftotext.cpp:105: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PDF_read_page(PDF*, int)’:
    pdftotext.cpp:119: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:119: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
    pdftotext.cpp:120: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:120: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘layout_mode’
    pdftotext.cpp:123: error: ‘page’ was not declared in this scope
    pdftotext.cpp:123: error: ‘struct PDF’ has no member named ‘doc’
    pdftotext.cpp:129: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:129: error: expected initializer before ‘rect’
    pdftotext.cpp:130: error: ‘rect’ was not declared in this scope
    pdftotext.cpp:133: error: ‘layout_mode’ was not declared in this scope
    pdftotext.cpp:133: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:135: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:137: error: ‘poppler’ has not been declared
    pdftotext.cpp:138: error: type ‘<type error>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-1mu2f1n2/pdftotext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ghuhvuhl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-1mu2f1n2/pdftotext/
```

I'm assuming the problem here is that it's looking for the C++ compiled files and I could only get the glib?

What I can look into?

Comment: Is the IT group's server running CentOS 7, by any chance? It looks as if poppler-cpp-devel is available on CentOS 7 but not on CentOS 6.

Comment: They're running `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`

Comment: Thanks for adding a self-answer here. Unfortunately that needed to be deleted, as we don't accept link-only answers. If you can expand it so the instructions are in the answer itself, with suitable attributions as necessary, that would be welcome.

Comment: @halfer I edited the response to include the full formatted text from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this. By following the instructions for installing `libpoppler-cpp` from this link, I was able to successfully install the `pdftotext`.

Following the instructions from [this repo](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools#building-from-source):

> **On CentOS**
>
> On CentOS the `libpoppler-cpp` library is not included with the system so we need to build from source. Note that recent versions of poppler require C++11 which is not available on CentOS, so we build a slightly older version of libpoppler.
>
> ```
> # Build dependencies
> yum install wget xz libjpeg-devel openjpeg2-devel
>
> # Download and extract
> wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.47.0.tar.xz
> tar -Jxvf poppler-0.47.0.tar.xz
> cd poppler-0.47.0
>
> # Build and install
> ./configure
> make
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> By default libraries get installed in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`. On CentOS this is not a default search path so we need to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point R to the right directory:
>
> ```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

*pdftotext* should be in **poppler-utils**, so try `yum install poppler-utils`

**EDIT:** Hmm. There's a package called *pypoppler* available for CentOS 6 in the EPEL repository, which describes itself as "Python bindings for the Poppler PDF rendering library." I see no indication that it includes *poppler/cpp/{anything}*, but you can give it a try. (You may need to install *pycairo* first.)

Failing that, you might try installing an [earlier version](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/#history) of *pdftotext* (e.g. `pip install pdftotext==1.0.0`) to find one compatible with CentOS 6. The earliest version came out in June of 2017, though, so that may not help.

I don't suppose you're interested in upgrading to CentOS 7?

Comment: I tried that one too but it's just the command line utilities. The Python library `pdftotext` distinctly seems to rely on the C++ wrapper for `poppler`.

Comment: For `pypoppler` I tried that too to no avail. And no option to upgrade the OS since I'm trying to emulate my company server.

I'll post and edit but my IT got back to me and they manually installed the CPP version so I asked how they did it. I plan to try to submit a pull request to the `pdftotext` github repo detailing my solution once I figure it out too.

Comment: I was able to install pdftotext==1.0.0 and then was able to update it to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

There actually is a proper CentOS 7 package. It is not enough to install the poppler-devel package as it does not include the CPP header files that is required and you simply need to install the poppler-cpp and poppler-cpp-devel packages:

yum install poppler-cpp poppler-cpp-devel

After this you can pip/pip3 install the pdftotext package without custom compiling and setting environment path variables.